# Django form validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there an easier way to write validation for each item in a form? Maybe embed them in model declaration itself?

```
class InfoUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [ 
                   'first_name',
                   'middle_name',
                   'last_name'
                 ]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        first_name = cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        if not str(first_name).isalnum():
            self._errors['first_name'] = self.error_class(['First name should constain only alpha numeric characters'])           
        middle_name = cleaned_data.get('middle_name')
        if not str(middle_name).isalnum():
            self._errors['middle_name'] = self.error_class(['Middle name should constain only alpha numeric characters'])           
        last_name = cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        if not str(last_name).isalnum():
            self._errors['last_name'] = self.error_class(['Last name should constain only alpha numeric characters'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `ModelForm` one way is to move the validation to `models.py` file (as you thought) and write [custom validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/#writing-validators):

validators.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def is_alpha_numeric(value):
    if not str(value).isalnum():
        raise ValidationError(
            ('%(value)s is not alpha-numeric'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

models.py:

```
from .validators import is_alpha_numeric

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[is_alpha_numeric])
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[is_alpha_numeric])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[is_alpha_numeric])
```

forms.py:

```
class InfoUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [ 
                   'first_name',
                   'middle_name',
                   'last_name'
                 ]
```

EDIT:

To pass any kind of [extra param](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542791/7100120), in your case the field name:

validators.py

```
class AlphaNumericValidator:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.field_name = kwargs['name']

    def __call__(self, value):
        if not str(value).isalnum():
            raise ValidationError(
                f'{self.field_name} value "{value}" is not alpha-numeric'
            )
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        validators=[AlphaNumericValidator(name='first_name')]
    )

    middle_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        validators=[AlphaNumericValidator(name='middle_name')]
    )

    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        validators=[AlphaNumericValidator(name='last_name')]
    )
```

Comment: How do I change error message to `First Name has to be alpha numeric` ?

Comment: You can implement a class based validator like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542791/7100120). I will update the answer with my solution.