# Django models, How do you pass datetime instead of a Datefield to validators?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I realize that validators need to be simple, however, I still rather use them instead of using the "clean/save functions" for this case.

What I have is a model called user (aka an employee) that has a joinDate and an exitDate. exitDate can be empty, however, when they are filled they need to be AFTER the joinDate (obviously).

```
class user(models.Model):
    joinDate = models.DateField()
    exitDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None,
                                validators=[secondDateAfterFirstDateValidator(joinDate)])
```

And the validator is a function that returns a function, just like it was recommended by this post [Is it possible to have validators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799744/is-it-possible-to-have-validators-with-parameters)

```
def secondDateAfterFirstDateValidator(joinDate):
    def innerfn(value):
        if value < joinDate:
            raise ValidationError("The exitDate must be after the joinDate")
    return innerfn
```

The error I get is:
'<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'DateField'

Now, the value that is being passed is what the validator is passing, which is the value of the DateField that the validator is being passed to (which is the exitDate). And this gets automatically converted from models.Datefield to 'datetime.date'.
However, it seems that when you pass to the validator the joinDate, it does not convert it to an instance of 'datetime.date' and keeps it as a models.Datefield.

How do I resolve this without relying on the clean/save methods? I also have other models like 'Project' in which it has a startDate and an endDate in which it will face a similar problem. I don't want to keep repeating the same validation in the clean/save method for every model that requires the second date > first date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can not and should not work with a validator. You're a trying to do validation accross multiple fields which should not be delegated to the fields themselves as only the model has all the necessary information to complete the validation.

Now, why it does not work. When you define the validator `exitDate`, you passed the field `joinDate` as parameter which is of type `models.CharField()`, you did not pass some kind of reference to the future value that will be this field when the validation will occurred. All of this has been resolved when the python class when instanciated, way ahead of the validation.
The post you linked use hard coded value as parameters of the validator, those could be defined inside the validator without any behavioural diffrence. The only purpose of parameter for validator is to factorise some code, not multi-field validation.

As you already know, you need to take a look at "clean/save functions"